# UML - Use case diagram for Booking module

Tags: uml

I'm developing a sidewalk renting app and it has a booking module, which is
described as below:

- The client (who rent the sidewalk) must login before starting booking
- The client needs to search for free sidewalk first, after login, before booking
- The client has to pay (more like selecting payment method, to be exact) to complete his booking
- To get to pay, the client has to view a detail result selected from the results list
- When viewing results list, the client can sort or filter results
- Searching must be done before booking, but no booking needed when performing search
- The client can get some help if they have any problems when booking

I don't know my diagram is correct or not, because I don't know which should be prioritized: the relationship between use cases or their order of executing.
If it's wrong, could you tell my why and show me some way to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Here is my diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your use case description, Client can perform two use cases only : book a sidewalk and login.

Others uses cases are steps to realize the booking : They are not included by others use cases and they can not be realized by other actor.

So, for me, you have one "main" use case only and the included use cases could appear as actions of an activity diagram for example.

The use cases which inherit from others are options of the use case "book a sidewalk", so I would use extension even.

Using this, the following diagram may be drawn. If I have to do it, I would have four extensions only : Get Help, Pay, Filter, and Sort. And I would provides details about them in extension description.

ps : since only Client inherits from User, I removed User from the diagram. I am not sure to understand the interest of a such inheritance, except if there are others actors not shown on the schema or it this is for future evolution.

[image: suggestion of an improvment]